# What is a production release of CUDA toolkit?

Tags: cuda

Earlier NVIDIA used to use the word **Release Candidate (RC)** for what was essentially a Beta release of the CUDA toolkit. A proper final release would follow pretty quickly in a month or two.

Now, CUDA 5.0 has been available as a **Production Release** for 4 months now. The long duration of its stay is leading me to wonder what Production Release means? Is the PR a stable release of CUDA 5.0 or will there be a later release of CUDA 5.0?

Comment: As far as I can tell "Production" code tends to be final so I would think this is a stable release of CUDA 5.0 and not a Beta.

Answer (score 4):

**Production Release** means the *final*, *stable* version of a toolkit, suitable for use in production.

**Release Candidate** is, as you say, essentially a beta release, except that it has the [potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle) to become the production release unless significant bugs are found.

For CUDA 5.0 there was a release candidate available for some period of time before the production release was published. You should go ahead and use CUDA 5.0!

Comment: NVIDIA has done an amazing job with the CUDA toolkit and IDEs. They're both extremely complex pieces of software to have been developed by what is essentially a hardware company. Having said that, NVIDIA has a history of very optimistic naming of their releases. Betas tend to be released as RCs, and what should be RCs are released for production. This, in effect, turns their customers into beta testers. Maybe CUDA 5.0 is different, but, if you don't need the features in 5.0, I'd say stay with 4.2 until there's a 5.1 or 5.2.